How to write big dataframes into an Icebergtable
I'm having a hive table with parquet files as storage. I'm inserting these files into a newly created icebergtable. Everything works fine as long as I dont exceed the source sice of 1 TB but as soon as I want to insert bigger sources like 30TB I have an overflow on my spark executor in the spark.local.dir.
spark 3.5
scala 2.12
My questions are

If I execute sourceData.writeTo(targetTableFullName).overwritePartitions()
I assume that my executor only has to handle one partition which would be around 40G max. As long as i dont join anything the executors don't have to interact?
Why is my spark.local.dir overflowing?

I already tried

increasing ephemeral storage. My biggest partition is 40GB and I set it to 100G
I tried out to set up a stream which worked but I dont like to introduce streaming into Batch
I checked spark.migrate and spark.snapshit

